# Add dots in table of contents for parts for LaTeX document

Tags: table-of-contents, parts

My document has three "parts" (using the `\part` command), and chapters, and sections. When I generate my table of contents (`\tableofcontents`), all the chapters and lower have dots between the name of the chapter/section/etc. and the page number. However, the parts do not have dots.

How do I fix this?

Here is the code in my cls that pertains to the table of contents, please advise how to make it so that parts also have dots.

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus 0.2em \@minus 0.2em
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}
    \begingroup
      \leftskip \z@ \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
      \parindent \z@
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern\@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern\@dotsep mu$}
      \hfil \nobreak\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\let\thesis@tableofcontents=\tableofcontents
\def\tableofcontents{{\singlespacing\thesis@tableofcontents}}
```

The document class [`uiucthesis2009`](https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/jhailpe2/www/uiucthesis2009.cls) is used and this class based on `book`:

```
\LoadClass{book}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the whole class?

Comment: Please note that "fixing issues with dots in ToC" usually means "getting rid of the dots": their very presence is the main problem (at least from aesthetical and functional points of view).

Comment: I agree with your general opinion mbork - but my university is requiring them for my dissertation....

Comment: @alan-munn - here is a link to the CLS file - https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/jhailpe2/www/uiucthesis2009.cls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You show the chapter code but not the part code, the dots come ffom this bit of `\l@chapter`

```
 \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern\@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern\@dotsep mu$}
  \hfil
```

If you look in your class file (or if it inputs one of the standard classes) you will find  \ definition of `\l@part` that just has `\hfil` (white space) rather than the leaders. eg `\l@part` in article has

```
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
```

putting the \leaders line between `#1` (the chapter title) and the `\hfil` will make the hfill work by repeating the dots rather than just using space.

like so:

```
\documentclass{uiucthesis}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1%
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern\@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern\@dotsep mu$}%
       \hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\part{the first}

\chapter{foo}

\section{hmmm}

aaa

\section{hmmm}

bbb

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @david-carlisle, my cls file has no \l@part in it. So what would i do to add it?

Comment: If part appears in the table of contents l@part must be defined, does your class \input or RequoreClass report or article class for example. You can find out the definition by adding \show\l@part but the error format breaks lines so it is nicer to copy from the original definition. (or just copy l@part from article.cls if you are really stuck)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The class was added in a comment above. The relevant part: `\LoadClass{book}`

Comment: Ah I see you gave a link it has `\LoadClass{book}` so take the definition of l@part from latex/base/book.cls, amended to have dots as in my answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I edited the question ;-)

Comment: possibly you forgot `\makeatletter` I added a working example to my answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tried inserting your block of code into my CLS file, and nothing changed. I put the `\renewcommand` you wrote right after the one for chapters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle... got it to work! The problem was that i had the `\makeletter` in my .tex file, and therefore these changes never got used!